# Resize image to lowest size with minimum quality loss

Tags: c#

I have this piece of code to resize picture:

```
public static void GetProductSmallThumbnail(string fileUrl, string fileName)
        {
            System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort myCallback =
            new System.Drawing.Image.GetThumbnailImageAbort(ThumbnailCallback);

            System.Drawing.Image img = null;
            FileStream fs = null;
            try
            {
                fs = new FileStream(fileUrl, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
                img = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(fs);
                int orgwidth = img.Width;
                int orgheight = img.Height;

                int imgwidth = img.Width;
                int imgheight = img.Height;

                // if 240 is max width
                imgwidth = 240;
                imgheight = Convert.ToInt32((imgwidth * orgheight) / orgwidth);
                System.Drawing.Image myThumbnail = img.GetThumbnailImage(
                imgwidth, imgheight, myCallback, IntPtr.Zero);
                myThumbnail.Save(Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets/products/small/" + fileName + ".jpg"));
            }
            finally
            {
                fs.Close();
            }

        }
```

Everything works correctly but the file size is much more than expected.
For example I used this image for Input:
[image]

The resulted image has correct width and height but the size is 89 KB, but I expect this image which is 7 KB

[image]

Comment: @michasaucer Wouldn't saving it as a JPG do that anyway?

Comment: OP, have you confirmed that `myThumbnail.Save(` does actually produce a jpeg file?

Comment: Dear @michasaucer how can I do that?

Comment: In my own test, your code produces a PNG file with a .JPG file extension.

Comment: Oh! How to correct it?

Comment: Read the [Remarks](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.getthumbnailimage?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#remarks) about the `Image.GetThumbnailImage` method.

Comment: Unfortunately the size I need has 240px width

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Save` function of `System.Drawing.Image` has an overload which accepts a format as its second parameter (see [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.image.save?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.1#System_Drawing_Image_Save_System_String_System_Drawing_Imaging_ImageFormat_)). To save your image in a format that is different from your original, pass the format to the save funtion:

```
myThumbnail.Save(
    Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "assets/products/small/" + fileName + ".jpg"),
    ImageFormat.Jpeg);
```